# Ubuntu 18.4 Try without install works 100%, but once installed it won't boot

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-drivers

Running 18.04 from a live USB everything is fine. Then I tried 2 installs. First time, I checked "install 3rd party software". login screen just redisplays itself after I enter password - from command line I see that startx fails with unspecified abort in x server. Second time, I did not check "install 3rd party software". Now the login screen will not recognize my password, so I can't use the command line to investigate further. Yes, I made sure of passwords :)

It is a new PC with intel processor and Z390 chipset with Nvidia RTX 2070 gfx card. It is dual boot with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. I just added 'nouveau.modset=0' in grub.
When you are in grub press 'e' and then on linux line add nouveau.modeset=0.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much.